# Form Validation using jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

As i'm very new to jQuery i'm having trouble validating my very first as well as very simple login form using jQuery validation.
I have searched for jQuery validation and have also seen many questions posted on the site but found them helpless for myself.

Here is my code.
Please help me finding out my mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>apply.html</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#testForm").validate({
        rules: {
            uname: { required: true },
            pwd: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            uname: { required: "Username can not be left blank" },
            pwd: { required: "Please enter Password" }
        }
    });
</script>
<form action="#" method="POST" id="testForm">
    Username :
    <input type="text" name="uname" /><br>
    Password :
    <input type="password" name="pwd" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Push">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :** the problem i'm facing is that on submitting the form no error message message is showing i.e. no validation taking place.

Comment: Keep in mind that any client-side validation can be bypassed so you have to validate once again on the server-side.

Comment: @DanGetz : It simply submitting the form without any error message.
Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your code with [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccy62nLv/) and it works properly. I assume the problem is that the code is not run after `onLoad()` event. Here's my solution:

```
$(function(){
    $("#testForm").validate({
        rules: {
            uname: { required: true },
            pwd: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            uname: { required: "Username can not be left blank" },
            pwd: { required: "Please enter Password" }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)
i just added
$(document).ready(function(){
// my jQuery code 
});

and it worked